# Configuring Cucumber with Cypress in Angular using cypress.config.ts

Tags: angular, cucumber, cypress

I am trying to configure Cucumber with Cypress in my Angular (15) project, but using cypress.config.ts file, since Cypress doesn't use cypress.json anymore.

I am having trouble, because Cypress is detecting .feature files, but can't seem to find steps.ts.

For Cucumber, I am using https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

My cypress.config.ts file looks like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import createEsbuildPlugin from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild";
const createBundler = require("@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor");


export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:4200",
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    async setupNodeEvents(
      on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
      config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions
    ): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

      on(
        "file:preprocessor",
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        })
      );

      return config;
    },
  },
});
```

I have added the following in package.json:

```json
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "json": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "stepDefinitions": [
      "cypress/e2e/**/*.{js,ts}",
      "cypress/e2e/tests/*.{js,ts}",
      "cypress/e2e/[filepath]/**/*.{js,ts}",
      "cypress/e2e/[filepath].{js,ts}",
      "cypress/e2e/tests/**/*.{js,ts}",
      "cypress/e2e/tests"
    ],
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  },
```

My project structure:

```
project
  - cypress
    - e2e
      - features (.feature files here)
      - tests (steps.ts files here)
  - src
    - app
      - components
      - services
  - ...
  - cypress.config.ts
  - package.json
```

The error I'm getting is:
**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vuk/.config/Cypress/cy/production/projects/project-2a46f44324c5a71cc0797383e08e1fda/bundles/cypress/e2e/features/my-profile.feature'**

Comment: The error message you're getting indicates that Cypress is unable to find the specified feature file. Are you sure the file path is correct?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, it would be easier if you replace your content from `package.json` into a new file named `.cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc`

where you should have something like:

```
{
  "json": {
    "enabled": true,
  },
  "stepDefinitions": [
    "cypress/e2e/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "omitFiltered": true,
  "filterSpecs": true,
  "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
}
```

Also, when you have

```
"cypress/e2e/**/*.{js,ts}"
```

it will include ALL the `.ts` files so the other step definitions are useless.